# NextJS error while trying to navigate to dynamic route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js

I'm making a next js App and it contains dynamic routing. For some reason i'm getting a message that says:

`Error: The provided path` X0UQbRIAAA_NdlgN`does not match the page:`/discounts/[itemId]`.'

I'm not sure if the problem has to do with the id. It's not my first time doing it, so I'm curious to solve this problem

The dynamic component is called [itemId].tsx and it's inside a discounts folder.

Main Dashboard

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { fetchApi } from '../lib/api-prismic';
import DiscountCard from '../components/DiscountCard';
import { Container, Heading, DiscountGrid } from '../styles/DiscountPageStyles';
import { motion, AnimateSharedLayout, AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';

export interface DiscountItem {
  node: {
    _meta: {
      id: string;
    };
    from: string;
    category: string;
    url_without_discount: string;
    discount_code: string;
    full_url: string;
    still_available: boolean;
    post_date: string;
  };
}

interface DashboardProps {
  discountItems: DiscountItem[];
}

const DiscountsDashboard: React.FC<DashboardProps> = ({ discountItems }) => {
  const [selectedCardId, setSelectedCardId] = useState<string | null>(null);

  return (
    <AnimateSharedLayout type="crossfade">
      <Container>
        <Heading>
          <h1>Discounter</h1>
        </Heading>

        <DiscountGrid>
          {discountItems.map((item) => (
            <Link
              href={`/discounts/${item.node._meta.id}`}
              key={item.node._meta.id}
            >
              <motion.div
                whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
                layoutId={item.node._meta.id}
              >
                <DiscountCard itemDetails={item} />
              </motion.div>
            </Link>
          ))}
        </DiscountGrid>
      </Container>
    </AnimateSharedLayout>
  );
};

export default DiscountsDashboard;

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const discountItems = await fetchApi(
    `
    query {
      allDiscountitems {
        edges {
           node {
            _meta {
              id
            }
            from
            post_date
            still_available
            category 
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
  `,
    {}
  );

  return {
    props: {
      discountItems: discountItems.allDiscountitems.edges,
    },
  };
}
```

[itemId].tsx

```
import React from 'react';

import {
  Wrapper,
  Container,
  Group,
  From,
  Availability,
  Content,
  Original,
  Code,
  Full,
  StillValid,
} from '../../styles/Modal';

import { AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';
import { DiscountItem } from '../discounts-dashboard';
import { fetchApi } from '../../lib/api-prismic';
import { GetStaticPaths, GetStaticProps } from 'next';

const SelectedModal = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {/* <Container>
        <Group>
          <From>{selectedItem.node.from}</From>

          <Availability>Posted: {selectedItem.node.post_date}</Availability>
        </Group>

        <Content>
          {selectedId && (
            <AnimatePresence>
              <Group>
                <Original>
                  Original URL: {selectedItem.node.url_without_discount}
                </Original>
                <Code>Discount Code: {selectedItem.node.discount_code}</Code>
              </Group>

              <Full>
                Complete URL:{' '}
                <a href={selectedItem.node.full_url}>
                  {selectedItem.node.full_url}
                </a>
              </Full>
            </AnimatePresence>
          )}

          <StillValid>
            <section
              style={{
                background: selectedItem.node.still_available
                  ? 'var(--bg-green)'
                  : 'var(--bg-red)',
              }}
            >
              <p
                style={{
                  color: selectedItem.node.still_available
                    ? 'var(--strong-green)'
                    : 'var(--strong-red)',
                }}
              >
                {selectedItem.node.still_available
                  ? 'Available'
                  : 'Unavailable'}
              </p>
            </section>

            <p>{selectedItem.node.category}</p>
          </StillValid>
        </Content>
      </Container> */}
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default SelectedModal;

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  const ids = await fetchApi(
    `
    query {
      allDiscountitems {
        edges {
          node {
           _meta {
              id
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `,
    {}
  );

  const allIds = ids.allDiscountitems.edges.map(
    (item: DiscountItem) => item.node._meta.id
  );

  return {
    paths: allIds,
    fallback: true,
  };
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const post = fetchApi(
    `
    query {
      allDiscountitems(id: $identifier) {
        edges {
          node {
            _meta {
              id
            }
            from
            post_date
            still_available
            category 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `,
    { identifier: params.id }
  );

  console.log(post);

  return {
    props: post,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What is showing up in your url bar when you click the link?  What happens if you go directly to the page `discounts/X0UQbRIAAA_NdlgN` or whatever your items id is by typing it in the url bar?

Right now I think your problem is that you are not registering the slug in your link component inside of brackets.  Read the bottom paragraph of the official docs [Here](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes).

> When routing to a dynamic route using Link or router, you will need to specify the href as the dynamic route, for example /post/[pid] and as as the decorator for the URL, for example /post/abc.

So in your `<Link/>` component the href should register the slug with the name you want to use inside of brackets like and then the name you want to show up in the url will be set in the as prop. So it should look something like the following:

```
<Link
  href='/discounts/[itemId]'
  as={`/discounts/${item.node._meta.id}`}
  key={item.node._meta.id}
>
  // your link content
</Link>
```

then you can catch the [itemId] in your component when navigated to the page

Comment: It does not work. Seems like I'm missing something... but I don't know what. It's been a long time since I built something with nextjs

Comment: I already tried to create a test file in the pages folder, and it works, so I'm missing something it the itemId file

Comment: Where is your discounts folder located? Is it in the pages folder?